# Unable to show new paragraph for html data into Textview in iOS Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, textview, nsattributedstring

I am working on iOS (Swift) application. I am getting some server response like below.

```
"description":"This is sample text to show in UI. When doing everyday activities.\u003cbr /\u003eclass is a strong predictor of life, and again sample text here.\u003cbr /\u003eSample text can show here also."
```

So, Above text has 3 paragraphs, I am trying to displaying them in `Textview`, But it is showing in plain with new line instead of New Paragraph.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            let description = jsonResponse["description"] as! String
            
            self.textView.attributedText = description.htmlAttributedString()


}
    extension String {
        func htmlAttributedString() -> NSAttributedString? {
            guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return nil }
            guard let html = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
                data: data,
                options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html],
                documentAttributes: nil) else { return nil }
            return html
        }
    }


The issue is it is showing text, But like new line showing instead of new paragraph. How to fix this?
```

[image]

Comment: When you convert the unicode chars in your description you will get the <br> which is equivalent to newline. I'm not sure what you mean by new paragraph.

Comment: The above text has 3 paragraphs. But it is coming like new line instead of new paragraph

Comment: this is how it looks when you decode them "This is sample text to show in UI. When doing everyday activities.<br />class is a strong predictor of life, and again sample text here.<br />Sample text can show here also."

Comment: As you see, there are <br> tags instead of <p>, if you want them to be new paragarph, try replacing <br> with <p>

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by following, And after conversion server response into json serialization, the special characters code showing as

So, I have fixed like below

```
    let description = jsonResponse["description"] as! String
    let formattedString = description.replacingOccurrences(of: "<br />", with: " \n\n")
    self.textView.text = formattedString
```